# SQL and C# (Windows Form Application) ,

Tags: c#, sql

[While I debug the code and try to add in my database this error pops up ,what can I do to overcome? #executenonquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoClK.png)

Comment: Please, provide your code (not a screenshot) and click on "View details" link

Comment: Seems it passes `"System.Wi..."` into `INSERT INTO students values(...)`. Is it expected ?

Comment: Michael is right (y) . just have to type (.Text) in that and done . thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the message says: One of the strings you try to insert is too long for the corresponding table column. Shorten the string to fit into the column (something like `left('whatever text is too long', 20)`) or increase the column's length (`alter table xy alter column xy varchar(50);` or so).